# Projective dimension of a sub-ideal

Tags: homological-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-dimension

Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a field, and let $S=\mathbf{k}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$. Let $I\subset J$ be finitely generated monomial ideals in $S$. Is it true that the projective dimension of $I$ is either smaller than or equal to the projective dimension of $J$?

Comment: No. $(x_1)$ has projective dimension $0$, while $(x_1x_2,x_1x_3)$  has projective dimension $>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, the equality you seek holds in one important special case. If $I$ is any monomial ideal and $J$ is the *radical* of $I$, then $pd_S(I)\leq pd_S(J)$. See the proof of Theorem 2.6 in this paper by [Herzog-Takayama-Terai](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412140).

Comment: Mr. Long_ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4031531/822157, I need to the help.